# How to get a model attribute value and assign it to another models attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

On a razor page I have two models - technician and tech_skill.  I am collecting skill data from the user and creating a tech_skill record with it but I don't want to have the user type in the technician Id - I want to get that from the technician object.

in the cshtml.cs file OnGet event I get the technician id.  There i then create the technician object.  Then on the cshtml page I know i have the technician because i can display their first and last names.

I have tried storing the technician id in a hidden field "Techs_Id" but I can to figure out how to then use that value in the form method="post" section.

Sorry if I have not explained this very well.

```
@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}
<h2>Create Tech_Skill Record</h2>
<hr />

<div>
    <h4>Technician</h4>
    <h3>
</div>

@Html.Hidden("Techs_Id", Model.technician.TechnicianId)

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div> 
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="tech_skill.Skill_Id" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="tech_skill.Skill_Id" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="tech_skill.Skill_Id" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
```

Comment: As I guess, you aren't using razor pages, but MVC. is it correct?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I would suggest you show the `OnGet()` method and the `PageModel` so we can better assist you with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**For Razor Pages:**

If I understood correctly you need to "somehow send" technician id to add tech skills to the specific technician. Inside form tags you need a button which post data to razor page handler:

```
 <form method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="tech_skill.Skill_Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="tech_skill.Skill_Id" class="form-control" />
       <span asp-validation-for="tech_skill.Skill_Id" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- and other code... -->
  <button type="submit" asp-page="/writeYourPageNameHere" asp-route-id="@Model.technician.TechnicianId" >Save Skill</button>
</form>
```

And your post method handler will look like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int id) //technicianId will be written in id 
{
   //you can use id here
   return RedirectToPage("pageNameYouWantToRedirectTo");
}
```

When you press button `OnPostAsync` method will be called and you can do anything you want in this method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your response.  It got me started on the right track (I am a complete newbie for this technology).  When I finally worked through what i was actually trying to do I came up with this solution:

```
    <form method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="tech_skill.Tech_Id" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="tech_skill.Tech_Id" class="form-control">
                <option value=@Model.technician.TechnicianId>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.technician.TechnicianId)</option>
            </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="tech_skill.Tech_Id" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

To get my technician Id into my tech_skill model i simply use a select with only one option being the tech Id.  Apologies for making you have to guess what I wanted to do.

cheers,

Greg.